# unrecognized option --build-id while compiling c++ code using g++

Tags: compiling, g++

well Im kinda new to ubuntu.
I tried compiling a c++ code.
it was a simple Hello world code.

I entered the following commands

```
g++ temp.cpp
```

and i get the following error message:--

```
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--build-id'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my g++ version is:-

```
muleyashutosh@VAIO:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

muleyashutosh@VAIO:~$ /usr/bin/ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.33
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

i couldn't understand what this meant as im just an engineering student.I googled a lot but still couldn't get a workthrough this..
Same error message for gcc compiler.
Hoping you guys could help.
I am running Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `g++ --version` and `/usr/bin/ld --version`

Comment: ya i made the changes as you asked